# Using Swiffy: How can i improve the quality of the images after converting it from flash to html5?

Tags: html, flash, google-swiffy

Im trying to convert excisting Flash banners to HTML5 with Swiffy. Although the quality of the images is very low and unsharp. Other answers on this topic did not helped me. What is the best type of image to use, JPG, PNG or does that not matter? Do i have to change something in the properties of the image or is there something else i did not see.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not quite a programming question...

Answer (score 0):

Keep all image assets in library uncompressed (100%). It'll help.